# Changes in the value of input type="time" in View is not reflected in Model of Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript

I am trying to Validate `input type="time":` but the changes in the view are not reflected in Model if any of the input is empty

**Example**
[image]
If user changes hour it's not reflected in the view.

[image]

whereas this works fine.

How do I make value available in the model if the input is partially filled?

Attempt so far:

1. I tried `(input)` and `(change)` but it did not work.
2. Tried `@ViewChild()` to access DOM element
3. Tried ReactiveForm `ValueChanges` method

**component**

```
  @ViewChild('ref') ref:ElementRef;
      name = 'Angular';
      time=new FormControl('')

      constructor(){
        this.time.valueChanges.subscribe(val=>console.log(val))
      }
      event(event)
      {
        console.log(event.target.value)

      }

      ngDoCheck()
      {
        console.log(this.ref.nativeElement.value)
      }
```

**Html**

```
<input type="time" #ref (input)="event($event)"  [formControl]="time">
```

**Note:**

> required Validator works fine but I need to get partially filled value
>   in my model.

**[`StackBlitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-timevalidation)**

Answer (score 1):

the time type is triggered when all the parts are full, after you fill the all parts you can trigger the changes in hour, minute and AM/PM.
for use in reactive form and check if all the parts are full you can use `Validators.required` validation and check until all parts are given:

```
time=new FormControl('', Validators.required )

constructor(){
  this.time.valueChanges.subscribe(val=>console.log('hi' , val))
}
submit(){
  console.log('form is' , this.time.valid);
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-timevalidation-gxzjae)

Comment: Thanks for the response Eventually I used 3rd Party Library for the same cuz requirements from the client were bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no direct way to accomplish since `HTML 5` itself set the value until all values of time are given. If any of the value is not provided the input value will set to undefined. So its nothing to do with `Angular`.

If you want to accomplish the same you need to write the custom component.